# Strange character in Swedish string

Tags: c#, string

I have a problem with a character in this Swedish string, where the character `å` is in fact 2 characters.

```
"Två"
```

Checking the length of the string:

```
"Två".Length
4
```

Checking each character in the string:

```
"Två"[0]
84 'T'
"Två"[1]
118 'v'
"Två"[2]
97 'a'
"Två"[3]
778 '̊'
```

Instead of being one `å` it's a combination of an `a` and some kind of `°` (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030a/index.htm)

How do I correctly replace one of these occurrences with the correct one-character letter?

Comment: `"Två".Replace("å", "å").Length;` will give you 3

Comment: That's odd. I'm swedish and I use the character å on a daily basis, as well as  C#, and I've never seen anything like this. May I ask how you get the å character into the editor in the first place?

Comment: I agree, I would like to know how you are getting this text.  This string: `Två`, returns length of 3 - [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bbzTmh)

Comment: It is a combining character, the string is not properly normalized.  The String.Normalize() method fixes the problem. Some combining characters cannot be normalized this way, but no problem with this one.  Do focus on where it came from.

Comment: @maccettura for test purposes, you can compose this string easily with unicode escapes:  `var escaped = "Tva\u030A";`  It's valid Unicode, just unnecessary way to represent the character.

Comment: @DanByström I'm also Swedish, I've coded C# for a lot of years now and I never saw this before. One of our users pasted it into our application.

Comment: @HansPassant `String.Normalize()` fixes the problem elegantly. Have to read up on that. I would accept this as the correct solution.